# how to call method inside class using MooseX::Declare

Tags: perl, oop

here "info_vcf" is a class where "info_vcf_function" is a method. "getValueFromInfoColum" and "getValueFromFormatColum" both are method which are present inside the "info_vcf_function" method.
now i want to call "getValueFromInfoColum" and "getValueFromFormatColum" both method from inside "info_vcf_function" method. how to do this ?

it gives me error " Validation failed for 'Tuple[Tuple[Object,Any],Dict[]]' with value "[ [ info_vcf=HASH(0x1ac7fd0), info_vcf=HASH(0x1ac7fd0), "anop" ], {  } ], Internal Validation Error is: \n [+] Valida
tion failed for 'Tuple[Object,Any]' with value "[ info_vcf={  }, info_vcf={  }, "anop" ]"\n  [+] More values than Type Constraints!" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/MooseX/Method/Signat
ures/Meta/Method.pm line 432.
        MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Method::validate(MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Method=HASH(0x3bd0e60), ARRAY(0x3154e80)) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/MooseX/Meth
od/Signatures/Meta/Method.pm line 148
        info_vcf::info_vcf_function(info_vcf=HASH(0x1ac7fd0), info_vcf=HASH(0x1ac7fd0), "anop") called at testone.pl line 24 "

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use MooseX::Declare;

class info_vcf {

    method info_vcf_function($selectedVariant) {

        print "$selectedVariant";
        getValueFromInfoColum("singh");
        getValueFromFormatColum("ranawat");

    }
        method getValueFromInfoColum($flag){
            print "$flag\n";
        }
        method getValueFromFormatColum($flag){
            print "$flag\n";
        }


}
1;

my $object = info_vcf->new();
$object->info_vcf_function("anop");
```

Comment: Are you talking about Perl 5 or Perl 6? Those are two different languages. Please [edit] and remove the tag that does not apply. Why do you want to create an instance of your class INSIDE THE DECLARATION of that class? And what error message? Please [edit] and copy/paste the **exact** error message.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation of your code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Good indentation is an important tool for helping people to understand your code. And if you're asking a group of strangers to read and understand your code, then it's polite to make that as easy as possible for them.

Comment: Note that the [documentation for MooseX::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Declare) is very clear that the module is deprecated. You should not be using it.

Comment: @anop.perl: Your last edit undid the formatting fix that I made. That's not very nice. I've re-applied them for you. And now you seem to have methods defined inside a method. Not sure what you think that is going to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Some confusion here. I'm not sure what you think this two lines are doing:

```
getValueFromInfoColum("singh");
getValueFromFormatColum("ranawat");
```

These are methods inside your class and need to be called on an object, i.e. like `$some_object->getValueFromInfoColumn($string)`. You can't just call them without an object (**update:** well, strictly, without an object or a class) as you do in this example. And why would you call them from within the class definition anyway?

With those two lines commented out, your code works as expected (although, it's more common for the class definition and the code that uses the class to be in separate files). But until you explain more about what you think those calls are doing, it's hard to give better advice than "remove the two broken lines".

**Update:** Also, note that class names in all lower case are reserved for *pragmata* - that is classes that change the behaviour of the Perl compiler simply by being loaded. Your class is not one of these, so you shouldn't use an all-lowercase name for it.

**Update 2:** Now you have added this to the question:

> now i want to call "getValueFromInfoColum" and "getValueFromFormatColum" both method from inside "info_vcf_function" method. how to do this ?

That's simple. You call a method on a particular object. Inside a method, the current object will be in the `$self` variable. So I think you want this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use MooseX::Declare;

class info_vcf {

    method info_vcf_function($selectedVariant) {
        print "$selectedVariant";
        $self->getValueFromInfoColum("singh");
        $self->getValueFromFormatColum("ranawat");
    }

    method getValueFromInfoColum($flag){
        print "$flag\n";
    }

    method getValueFromFormatColum($flag){
        print "$flag\n";
    }
}
1;

my $object = info_vcf->new();
$object->info_vcf_function("anop");
```

As I said in a comment, [MooseX::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Declare) is deprecated. That means you shouldn't be using it for new code. The documentation recommends using [Moops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops) instead.

Comment: thanks,  but how to create object inside class using MooseX::Declare. getValueFromInfoColum("singh") and getValueFromFormatColum("ranawat") both are methods inside class

Comment: @anop.perl: I have no idea what that means. Please edit your question to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Re "*You can't just call them without an object*", It that true? Or did you mean you can't call them without an *invocant*. I suspect you can use `__PACKAGE__->method()` for a class method.

Comment: @ikegami: You're right, of course. I was trying to to keep the explanation simple. Perhaps I over-simplified. I've added an update to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, but you go own to ask "why would you call them from within the class definition anyway?". If they're class methods, it makes sense. That said, the method names don't suggest class methods.

Comment: @ikegami: The documentation is vague, but the error message ("Validation failed for 'Tuple[Object,Any]'") makes me think that the `method` keyword is only for defining object methods. Anyway, the module is heavily deprecated, so it shouldn't be used anyway.

Comment: thanks Dave Cross, but still it is not working, i have modified code as you suggested.

Comment: @anop.perl: "still it is not working" is not exactly helpful. Exactly what unexpected behaviour are you seeing? Edit your question, show us the exact code that you are using.

Comment: Ah. I've just seen (and fixed) the error that I copied from an earlier version of your code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone, finally its working

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use MooseX::Declare;

class info_vcf {

    method info_vcf_function($selectedVariant) {
        print "$selectedVariant";
        $self->getValueFromInfoColum("singh");
        $self->getValueFromFormatColum("ranawat");
    }

    method getValueFromInfoColum($flag){
        print "$flag\n";
    }

    method getValueFromFormatColum($flag){
        print "$flag\n";
    }
}
1;

my $object = info_vcf->new();
$object->info_vcf_function("anop");
```